# xamarin iOS using shared project with HttpClient not working

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, httpclient

I have a Xamarin android project set up using a shared project for all of my network services that works great.  In that shared project I have a class with a method that is calling a REST endpoint via `HttpClient.PostAsync()`.  I am now working on the iOS version and thought this would be pretty painless to just use the same classes/methods that I've already fleshed out for android but for some reason, iOS is not working.

I'm not getting any exceptions being thrown, just the call to `PostAsync()` seems to die and not do anything that I can tell.  I have also tried a `GetAsync()` call with the same result...nothing happens.

Here is some example code:

```
public class UserService
{
    public async Task<UserModel> LoginUser(UserModel userModel)
    {
        var url = new Uri(Constants.BaseUrl + "v2api/LoginUser");
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                string userModelString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userModel);
                var response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(userModelString, Encoding.Default, "application/json"));
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    userModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserModel>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string exceptionString = e.ToString();
        }
        return userModel;
    }
}
```

I've put breakpoints all over this and it gets to the: v`ar response = await` line, but that's it.  I never get anything returned.  As mentioned above, this works great with the android project, it's only iOS that's not working.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something really simple, I just don't know what it could be.

I have tried adding this to my `info.plist` file, but it didn't help:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mysite.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

any suggestions of where to look next?

tia

Comment: a) Are you using the Managed provider or the NSUrlSession provider? b) Review the device log for any faults c) Is your site using a self-signed cert?

Comment: This is my first xamarin ios project so I'm pretty green.  1) I'm not sure what you mean by managed provider or NSUrlSession provider.  I have just created a utility class in my xamarin.ios project that I'm calling this method from in my shared project 2) how can I see the device log?  I'm testing on an iPhone 6 physical device. 3) no, right now I'm just calling an http (not https) endpoint.

Comment: So since you are using `http` the httpclient provider (see the project setting / iOS build options for this setting) and self-signed cert issues on iOS are not in play. If you are debugging on the iOS device, you can see the device log via the app output panel or the device log panel inside VS4M.

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for the clarification.  I have now seen what you mean by the different providers and I"m a little embarrassed that I didn't discover that before (again, this is my first iOS attempt...I'm more of an android guy).  I tried a few different providers and in the output window for managed, I see it starting a new thread, but no errors that I can tell.  In the output window for NSUrlSession, it says ATS has blocked a cleartext HTTP resource... so I feel like that is at least getting further.  It seems like it should see my allowed exception though in the info.plist file right?

Comment: @SushiHangover turns out I was missing a key (<key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>) in info.plist.  I added that and the error went away in the output window, but it still isn't doing anything on the HttpClient.PostAsync() call.  It's like that method call just swallows everything up inside my LoginUser() method and everything stops.

Comment: so I've done some more troubleshooting and discovered that WebClient works as does WebRequest so it's something to do with my version of HttpClient in iOS.  I'll keep playing with it to see if I can downgrade to a different version or something, but if anyone has any ideas, I'd love to get this problem solved.  I'd really like to use HttpClient instead of WebRequest or WebClient.

Comment: and after some more troubleshooting, I've determined that HttpClient does indeed work, but only on syncrounous calls.  So my failure appears to be happening only when I await the response.  This doesn't happen on Android, only on iOS.  Is there something I need to enable to allow multithreading for iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got this sorted out after doing some more googling.  This thread was my exact problem: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17086/httpclient-postasync-doesnt-work-when-awaited

I was calling my login method with a .Result; and apparently that doesn't work in iOS but strangely it does in Android.

Sushi, thanks for the education in iOS Http stuff :)